# Playing .aif file in android

Tags: android, audio, android-sdk-2.3, aiff

Is there any way to play .aif file in Android ?

I refer bellow link to play audio file in my application.

http://www.androidhive.info/2012/03/android-building-audio-player-tutorial/

.aif audio file is not played in above tutorial code.

Any idea ?

Answer (score 2):

Please refer to this > [Supported Media Formats](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html)